# FBConnect - template not using my template bundle

Tags: fbconnect

I registered a template bundle for my app, one that only uses *actor*, so I brought it up like this:

```
FBFeedDialog* dialog = [[[FBFeedDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
dialog.delegate = self;
dialog.templateBundleId = 12345;
[dialog show];
```

(using my bundle id, of course)

But all I get when the dialog comes up is "Do you want to publish this story to your Profile?".  The "story" doesn't show up in the dialog, and if I click Publish I end up with a blank story in my feed.

Then I tried registering another one which a) has only a one-line story, to make things simpler (the first one had everything) and b) uses a custom key.

```
FBFeedDialog* dialog = [[[FBFeedDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
dialog.templateBundleId = 12345;
dialog.templateData = @"{\"flavor\": \"chocolate chip\"}";
[dialog show];
```

Same result, blank story.  I've done a lot of google searching and can't find anyone else with this problem, so I must be doing something incredibly silly.  Can anyone advise, please?

Comment: You need to learn about markdown formatting: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help In particular, code needs to be indented with 4 spaces to format correctly.

Comment: Sorry - it looked ok in the preview window so I thought it was ok.  I guess you fixed it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, but I don't quite understand the fix (I'm new to Obj-C as well as iPhone).

I have an ivar called session, which stores the FBConnect session, for which I had an @property and @synthesize as usual.  I removed both of those and explicitly retained the session when it was allocated, instead of relying on the property to do it, and it started working.  I don't see how these are functionally different, but in comparing my code to the sample, which worked, I noticed this difference and tried it.  The release is in the dealloc method, which is where it was all along.

I would love an explanation if anyone can give one!